# When I create a list of list in Python, why do all my inner lists get the same values?

Tags: python, arrays, list, pointers

So, I was working on Python for making List of arrays for my project work.

Sample code:

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 0
car = [0,0]
listitem = [car[:] for i in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
    car[0] = var0 + i + 1
    car[1] = var1 + i
    listitem[i] = car
print listitem
```

As the logic would suggest we would be expecting an output like:

```
[[1,0],[2,1],[3,2],[4,3],[5,4],[6,5],[7,6],[8,7],[9,8],[10,9]]
```

But the output comes as:

```
[[10,9],[10,9],[10,9],[10,9],[10,9],[10,9],[10,9],[10,9],[10,9],[10,9]]
```

I have come with a theory where the car array uses some pointers to the variable space.

Does anyone has a probable explanation for the same?
Thank you

Comment: You're explicitly replacing all of the list copies you create with the original `car`. Move the shallow copy into the `for` loop.

Comment: No need for downvoting, but this has been asked many times before, e.g., [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/2749397).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you run this code 'listitem[i]=car',you assign the car's memory address to listitem[i], and the address for car is the same everytime. After the 10 times loop, all the subitem in listitem will point the same address. If you run  below code :

```
 for i in range(10):
    car[0] = var0 + i + 1
    car[1] = var1 + i
    listitem[i] = car
    print hex(id(listitem[i]))
```

you will get the answer. At the last time the address for car saved with [10,9] so all the output is the same thing

Try this one :

```
  for i in range(10):
    listitem[i]=[a,b]=[var0 + i + 1,var1 + i]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're recycling the car variable in the loop, and so all your entries in listitem point to the same object.

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 0
car = [0,0]
listitem = [car[:] for i in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
    car = listitem[i]
    car[0] = var0 + i + 1
    car[1] = var1 + i
    listitem[i] = car
print listitem
```

See [@simon-fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527520/simon-fraser)'s comment below for more info on why this is the case.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning `id()` to help the explanation?  `for item in listitem: print(id(item))` shows they're all the same underlying object in the original post, and all different in yours

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no need to initialise all the elements of `listitem` as you can append to it. There is also no need to use a variable `car` as you can immediately store the items you create in `listitem`

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 0
listitem = []
for i in range(10):
    listitem.append([var0 + i + 1, var1 + i])
print listitem
```